# Sorting bounded rectangles in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a set of bounded rectangles as Rect in a vector.

```
vector(Rect) boundRect( contours.size() );
```

I want to sort these rectangles like in the image below

[image http://img42.com/liVFt](http://img42.com/liVFt)

I have already tried using the method below, but I am not getting the order like in the image I have posted.

```
stable_sort( boundRect.begin(), boundRect.end(), compareX_rect );
stable_sort( boundRect.begin(), boundRect.end(), compareY_rect );

bool compareX_rect(const Rect & a, const Rect &b) {
    return a.x >= b.x;
}
bool compareY_rect(const Rect & a, const Rect &b) {
    return a.y >= b.y;
}
```

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combine into a single sort where the sort will compare y value first, then next on x value:

EDIT: Fixed the sort Tested on coding ground:

```
bool compareFn(Rectangle* l, Rectangle* r) {
    if(l->y == r->y) return l->x < r->x;
    return (l->y < r->y);
}
```

And to reduce noise (depending how much noise is involved) you can do a floor or round function, or calculate a 'cell' that the y value is a part of. Just increase the cell size until it overcomes the noise:

```
float cellSize = 20.0f;
bool compareFn(Rectangle* l, Rectangle* r) {
    float lCell = floorf(l->y / cellSize);
    float rCell = floorf(r->y / cellSize);
    if(lCell == rCell) return l->x < r->x;
    return (lCell < rCell);
}
```

And here's the program testing it (without noise reduction):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort

using namespace std;

struct Rectangle {
    float x;
    float y; 
    float width; 
    float height;

    Rectangle(float x_, float y_, float w_, float h_)
    : x(x_)
    , y(y_)
    , width(w_)
    , height(h_)
    {}

};

bool compareFn(Rectangle* l, Rectangle* r) {
    if(l->y == r->y) return l->x < r->x;
    return (l->y < r->y);
}

int main()
{
   vector<Rectangle*> rectangles;
   for(int x=0; x<10; ++x) {
       for(int y=0; y<10; ++y) {
           Rectangle* rect = new Rectangle((9 - x) * 50, (9-y) * 50, 50, 50);
           rectangles.push_back(rect);
       }
   }

   printf("SORTING\n");
   sort(rectangles.begin(), rectangles.end(), compareFn);

   printf("RESULTS\n");
   for(vector<Rectangle*>::iterator it=rectangles.begin(), end=rectangles.end(); it!=end; ++it) {
       Rectangle* rect = *it;
       printf("[%f, %f, %f, %f]\n", rect->x, rect->y, rect->width, rect->height);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work if there is some small noise within y coord of the same row, does it?

Comment: correct, if there is some noise just do a round or a floor function on the y's. Or even add a noise threshold to the comparison.

Comment: I tried using the approach you suggested using the floor function. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the results you are getting? The idea: rectangles on the same row should be sorted by x and those on differing rows should be sorted by y. So if you have noise, you have to reduce the noise enough to make same row rectangles match on their y.

Comment: I tested the sort personally. I had the right concept, just implemented the logic a little wrong :) This fn is much clearer. Literally, if the y's are the same then compare on x, otherwise compare on y. This printed out the correct order for me. I edited my original post with the correction.

Comment: Diniden, your logic is correct. The problem I am facing is with the noise. Within the same row the rectangles are not ordered. I tried with the floor function, still it isn't working.

Comment: You can eliminate noise also by cell grouping ranges: I will edit my post to include some noise reduction